# How to insert a PDF attachment into NSAttributedString and display in a UITextView

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UITextView where I want to allow the user to insert photos from the photo library and PDFs from a document picker.

It is quite easy to embed a photo into the text view attributed string:

```
        let attachment = NSTextAttachment(data: image.jpegData(1.0), ofType: kUTTypeJPEG as String)
        attachment.bounds = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: 40, height: 40))
        let attachmentString = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
        let text = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: textView.attributedText)
        text.append(attachmentString)
        textView.attributedText = text
```

This works perfectly for a photo: the image displays in the UITextView and the attachment is retrievable from the attributedText:

```
            textView.attributedText.enumerateAttribute(.attachment, in: NSMakeRange(0, attributedText.length), options: []) { (item, range, ptr) in
            if let attachment = item as? NSTextAttachment {
                files.append(FileAttachment(data: attachment.contents, type: attachment.fileType))
            }
```

The problem comes when trying to attach a PDF.
If I follow the exact same pattern with a PDF, replacing the data with PDF data and file type with kUTTypePDF, the attachment is created but does not display anything in the UITextView.

I should simply be able to set an image on the NSTextAttachment as a representation of the contents but this resets the attachment data.

```
        let data = Data(contentsOf: pdfURL)
        let attachment = NSTextAttachment(data: data, ofType: kUTTypePDF as String)
        attachment.image = UIImage(named: "pdf-document-icon")
        attachment.bounds = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: 40, height: 40))
        let attachmentString = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
        let text = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: textView.attributedText)
        text.append(attachmentString)
        textView.attributedText = text
```

Now, the PDF attachment displays in the text view as a nice icon, but later when I enumerate the attachments the contents and file type are nil. i.e. setting an image on NSTextAttachment resets contents and fileType

I need to both set content and separate image representing the content on NSTextAttachment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I have come up with so far is to subclass NSTextAttachment:

```
class TextAttachmentWithThumbnail: NSTextAttachment {
    private var thumbnail: UIImage?

    override var image: UIImage? {
        get { return thumbnail }
        set { thumbnail = newValue }
    }
}
```

So that setting an image no longer resets contents and fileType